# OpenCV PS 3 Eye

Tags: linux, opencv

I am on Ubuntu 10.10 and trying to capture video from a ps3eye camera, afaik OpenCV uses v4l for capturing from webcams, gucview, cheese, vlc all can access and use the camera but when using opencv to capture from it I get blank frames.

```
 /**
 * Display video from webcam
 *
 * Author  Nash
 * License GPL
 * Website http://nashruddin.com
 */

//gcc test.c -I /usr/include/opencv/ -L /usr/lib/ -lcv -lhighgui

#include <stdio.h>
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    CvCapture *capture = 0;
    IplImage  *frame = 0;
    int       key = 0;

    /* initialize camera */
    capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( -1 );

    /* always check */
    if ( !capture ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Cannot open initialize webcam!\n" );
        return 1;
    }

    /* create a window for the video */
    cvNamedWindow( "result", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

    while( key != 'q' ) {
        /* get a frame */
      frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );

        /* always check */
      if( !frame ) break;

        /* display current frame */
        cvShowImage( "result", frame );

        /* exit if user press 'q' */
        key = cvWaitKey( 1 );
    }

    /* free memory */
    cvDestroyWindow( "result" );
    cvReleaseCapture( &capture );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried passing 0 or 1 to cvCaptureFromCAM() instead of -1 ?

Comment: Which OpenCV version are you using?

Comment: there is only one camera I tried 0, no luck, opencv version is 2.1 from ubuntu repos, I also tried 2.2 compiled from source same problem.

Comment: i have same problem here, did you find any solution ?