# Grabbing Images from a Webcam to be used with OpenCV

Tags: linux, image-processing, opencv

This is a follow up to my previous question,

[OpenCV PS 3 Eye](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031892/opencv-ps-3-eye)

Can someone suggest a library that would allow me grab frames from camera without too much fuss (like video videoinput lib for windows) and pass them to opencv within my application?

Comment: You are probably better off finding out why openCV doesn't work with your webcam - any other lib is likely to use the same V4L layer

Comment: if you read me prev question everyother application that uses v4l works except opencv.

Answer (score 7):

I had a parallel problem using a completely different webcam: worked well in cheese/etc, `v4l-info` showed proper setup, but openCV would fail with:

`HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L2: Pixel format of incoming image is unsupported by OpenCV
Unable to stop the stream.: Bad file descriptor`

After much flailing I found that [at least one guy](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/opencv/+bug/321358?comments=all) had similar problems with webcams in various applications.

In blind faith I promptly punched in `export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so` and «*poof*» it worked.

The openCV v4l2 interface is not as robust as the v4l implementation and the export is a quick [workaround](http://www.linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/libv4l.html#id2858949) (openCV appears to revert to v4l).

With a quick browse of `opencv/modules/highgui/src/cap_v4l.cpp` it would appear as though openCV would like to use v4l2.

I'm running Ubuntu Lucid 2.6.32-28-generic x86_64, libv4l-0 v0.6.4-1ubuntu1 with openCV pulled from the HEAD of the repo a few days ago.

In the course of explaining this I've resolved my issue. It turns out that openCV forces the resolution on a v4l2 device to 640x480 by default - and my device had a max 320x240 resolution which caused the fault when testing for the format type in `opencv::highgui::cap_v41::try_palette_v4l2`. I changed *DEFAULT_V4L_WIDTH* and,  *DEFAULT_V4L_HEIGHT*.